# Parsing JSON file to image list PHP

Tags: php, json, image

I'm trying to parse a JSON file called photos.json, in a PHP file called photos.php.

I also have a `gallery.php` file where the results will be displayed. I am hoping to retrieve a gallery of images from a JSON file with image links. I am having trouble parsing JSON in the PHP file. I can do the image styling.

Here is my JSON file:

```
{
    "result": {
        "title": "Gallery",
        "posts": [
            {
                "title": "Test1",
                "img": "localhost/photos/img/gallery/test1.png",
                "tags": "test,1"
            },
            {
                "title": "Test2",
                "img": "localhost/photos/img/gallery/test2.png",
                "tags": "test,2"
            },
            {
                "title": "Test3",
                "img": "localhost/photos/img/gallery/test3.png",
                "tags": "test,3"
            },
            {
                "title": "Test4",
                "img": "localhost/photos/img/gallery/test4.png",
                "tags": "test,4"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my PHP file:

```
<?php
$json_file = file_get_contents('photos.json');\
$jfo = json_decode($json_file);\
$title = $jfo->result->title;
$posts = $jfo->result->posts; 
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->title;
}
?>
```

Note: photos.json and photos.php are in the same directory (localhost/photos/img/photos(.php or .json)

Here is my a snippet of my gallery.php file:

```
<ul class="ul_json clearfix">
<?php
  foreach ($posts as $post) {
?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo $post->img; ?>">
      <h2><?php echo $post->title; ?></h2>
      <img src="<?php echo $post->img; ?>">
    </a>    
  </a>
</li>
<?php
  } // end foreach
?>
```

Edit: I am also getting the error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(photos.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: And what do you want from us?

Comment: In below code you are trying to echo `$post->link` ,  `link` it is not present in your json.

Comment: I fixed that. But I am still getting the issue I mentioned in the edit.